# Problem inserting data into a sharepoint list

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint

I'm using MS Access to insert data into a sharepoint list.
I created the following SQL query to do this:

```
INSERT INTO [SP List] ( Title, Date, Name )
SELECT local.ID, local.Date, local.Name
FROM local;
```

However, when running this query, it inserts only the value of the column `"Title"` of Sharepoint. The value of all other columns are always entered in blank.

Even if I open the sharepoint table inside Access and insert a new row manually, typing the values ​​of each column, only the column `"Title"` receives those values. The other columns always remains in blank.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

*Date* is a reserved word, and *Name* and *local* may be, so try:

```sql
INSERT INTO [SP List] ( Title, [Date], [Name] )
SELECT local.ID, local.Date, local.Name
FROM [local];
```